# Post JSON to Razor Page, return HTML

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

After a user fills out a form, I need post the form contents back in JSON and get a chunk of HTML back for display.  This seems like a good case for razor pages.  The BrandTemplateInfo parameter on the OnPost handler is always null.  I can't seem to get the BrandTemplateInfo to populate from the model binder.  What am I missing here?  This used to be easy with MVC controllers.  What am I missing here?  Help?

```
public class PayNowCardModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost([FromBody] BrandTemplateInfo brandTemplateInfo)
    {
        return Page();
    }


    public BrandTemplateInfo BrandTemplateInfo { get; set; }
}
```

HTTP Request:

```
POST /terms/paynowcard HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "userForm": {
        "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
        "paymentAmount": 123.33
    },
    "account": {
        "Creditor": {
            "Name": "big time creditor"
        },
        "accountId": "32432432432423"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408628/post-json-to-from-razor-pages OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783104/cannot-post-json-to-an-asp-net-core-razorpage-handler

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the `BrandTemplateInfo` object has the same name properties as the posted json property :

```
public class BrandTemplateInfo
{
    public userForm userForm { get; set; }

    public account account { get; set; }
}

public class account
{
    public Creditor Creditor { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
}

public class Creditor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class userForm
{
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
    public float paymentAmount { get; set; }
}
```

So that model binding would work with `[FromBody]` attribute .